# I'm getting a StringOutOfBoundsException in part of a java Project

Tags: java, string, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

```
else if (args.length == 5)
    {
        String firstyear = args[3];
        String secondyear = args[4];
        String datayear = temp[0];
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date first = df.parse(firstyear);
        Date second = df.parse(secondyear);
        Date datas = df.parse(datayear);
        weekday = convertDateToWeekDay(temp);
        if (weekday == day || day == 0);
        {
            if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                    || drawtype.contentEquals("A")) {
                if ((datas.equals(first)) || (datas.equals(second))
                        || ((datas.after(first)) && (datas.before(second)))) {
                    if (choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
                        for (int count = 0; count < jackpot.length; count++) {
                            jackpot[count] = Integer
                                    .parseInt(temp[count + 1]);
                            jackpotnumbers[jackpot[count] - 1]++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (choice == 2) {
                        bonus = Integer.parseInt(temp[7]);
                        if (temp[8].contentEquals(drawtype)
                                || drawtype.contentEquals("A"))
                            bonusnumbers[bonus - 1]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is a piece of a project I have to do for college. Its purpose is to analyse lotto information between two dates and for different draws. It is giving this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

It takes in two dates from the command line.It reads a line from a file and puts it into an array called temp. The rest of the program works fine but if it goes into this part it crashes and gives that error. Can anyone spot what's causing the error. I also know I can write this better, but I want it to work first before I focus on making it good code.

Edit: bonusnumbers and jackpotnumbers are both int arrays that are 45 long.temp is a string array with the temp[0] being a date such as 10/07/1994.jackpot is an int array that is 45 long.
if(weekday == day || day == 0); this is to check that that date read from the file is a certain day supplied by the user.
I dont know what you mean by stack trace or use the debugger.I am new to programming

edit 2: I know that the error is in this section because it only crashes when I run this section.I can run the other parts of the code without it crashing.After this error it just says the name of each method

Comment: Well which line is throwing the exception? Can you simplify the code sample to a short but complete program which *just* demonstrates the problem. It would also *really* help  if you could format your code - it's very hard to read without proper indentation.

Comment: Could you paste the first 10 lines of the stack trace?

Comment: try to narrow it to more specific line of code. the bit of code you showed us has many variables that are not defined/assigned to in that part of the code (they might be before, but we can't know this). Use your debugger, where exactly the exception throws?

Comment: what does this line do? `if(weekday == day || day == 0);`

Comment: too many unknowns: `bonusnumbers`, `temp`, `jackpot`, `jackpotnumbers`. How do you expect us to help?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're **"new to programming"** so you don't **"know what [is meant] by stack trace or use the debugger"**. How, then, do you *know* that it is this chunk of code that is causing the problem? You must've seen something in the console of your IDE (assuming you're using an IDE or perhaps you're running this from the command-line? In either case, there should've been a lot lines of text immediately after the one you posted saying things like **"at java..."**. Anyway, if that is present, then that is your stacktrace (basically, the lines of execution of your program that led up to your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

Regardless, since it is throwing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, I would say your `contentEquals(...)` method calls are highly suspect. But, as others have stated, it is impossible to say without more information.